# Only show whats between "q=" and "&" and then replace "+" with spaces

Tags: jquery

Inside a table i have a long url. What i want to do is show only whats between "q=" and "&" and make the font-size: 24px

```
<tr>        <td width="200" class="FieldLabel">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;            9d.seguimiento:&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        http://www.google.com.ar/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=CZPDPFa0nUpy_NqnjiQKLnoGgC9TDidMFlMbTsIYBzLCy5o8BCAAQASgDUOaitkNgodCEgCygAbz01eADyAEBqQINBW5nwYqHPqoEI0_QlKOMbJ1F4PozVQrINTA87n7cOIGvayY5KKXi7nFbfoiDgAesi6of&amp;sig=AOD64_15b8YaU3U1t7e8ZNZ04mEVVZsw4g&amp;rct=j&amp;q=seguros+banco+provincia&amp;ved=0CC4Q0Qw&amp;adurl=http://segurosendirecto.com.ar/cotizador-de-seguros-auto?kw=seguros%2520banco%2520provincia       </td>
```

The way i select the element with jquery is:

```
$('#fichadelcontacto tr:contains("9d.seguimiento")')
```

How can i show only whats between "q=" and "&" and then replace the "+" with actual spaces?

Comment: Use a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = $("td.FieldLabel").next().text(); // i guess the selector is good
var match = url.match(/q=([^&]+)/);
```

`match[1]` will contain what you need, see the paranthesis for the group. If match failed, match will be null and you will get an error if you try to access match[1]

```
var result = match[1].replace(/\s+/, "+");
```

However, I think you are looking for `encoding/decoding URI components`, check these functions too.

Also, `$("td.FieldLabel").next()` is the table data, you can manipulate its CSS by css method, so you should add `.css("font-size", "24px");`

Edit:
Working JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aYLkV/12/

Comment: can you provide a working jsfiddle of your suggestion based on tmy html?

Comment: @sebas I have updated my answer with the working JS Fiddle. I hope that it is what you want.

Comment: Thank you but how would you replace the "+" with a space " "

Comment: anyTextVariable.replace(/\+/g, " "). You have to escape(\) the + sign because it is a quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// get substring between `=` and `&`
var String=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("=")+1,str.lastIndexOf("&"));
// replace `+` with ` `
String.replace(/+/g,' ');
```

Comment: Will fail if URL looks like : some-url?q=thedesiredtext&a=b&c=d. If you really want to do it with indexOf, get the substring containing q= and AFTER that, look for the first &.